# Given a Rails 5 has_and_belongs_to_many, how to create a join record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I have the following schema:

```
class Industry << ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :departments
end

# Relationship table: departments_industries

class Department << ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :industries
  has_and_belongs_to_many :job_titles
end

# Relationship table: departments_job_titles

class JobTitle << ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :departments
end
```

When I want to create a relationship record:

```
department.job_titles.find_or_create_by(title: title)
```

The above DOES end up creating a record in `departments_job_titles` ONLY if the query above create's the record... If the JobTitle already exists, Rails is NOT creating the relationship record in `departments_job_titles`.

How can I update:

```
department.job_titles.find_or_create_by(title: title)
```

To always create the relationship record in `departments_job_titles` when either the JobTitle record is found or created?

Comment: In Rails style guide (https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#activerecord ctrl+F "has_and_belongs_to_many") it is recommended to use `has_many :things, through: :join_records` instead of HABTM, as it (quoting) *"allows additional attributes and validations on the join model"* (like `favorite`, `position` attributes, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```ruby
department.job_titles << JobTitle.find_or_create_by(title: title)
```